# Time-series clustering Quality Measures

Tags: clustering, time-series, unsupervised-learning, performance

I am clustering time-series datasets which are not labeled (No Ground truth) and I want to measure the quality of the clusters. 
Could you please suggest any Clustering performance evaluation methods that can be used in time-series clustering ??

Answer (score 0):

Clustering evaluation metrics basic goal is to measure the similarity within each cluster and dissimilarity among clusters; if a clustering algorithm has achieved those two things in an acceptable degree than it has performed well.

The most commonly used evaluation metrics are:

-Silhouette Coefficient - it is the most popular one for time-series clustering ([implementation for python](https://tslearn.readthedocs.io/en/stable/gen_modules/clustering/tslearn.clustering.silhouette_score.html) can be found in tslearn.clustering package)

-Davies-Bouldin Index ([implemenation for python](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.davies_bouldin_score.html) can be found in sklearn package)

-Dunn's index

You might find the following articles useful sources to help you understand those metrics:

- ["Evaluation Metrics for Clustering" in Medium](https://medium.datadriveninvestor.com/evaluation-metrics-for-clustering-96dcdbea437d)
- [Article with presentation of Evaluation Metric for Supervised and Unsupervised learning](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2020/10/quick-guide-to-evaluation-metrics-for-supervised-and-unsupervised-machine-learning/)
- [Explanation of Dunn index and DB index](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dunn-index-and-db-index-cluster-validity-indices-set-1/)
- [An example using Silhouette score on time-series clustering](https://towardsdatascience.com/time-series-clustering-deriving-trends-and-archetypes-from-sequential-data-bb87783312b4)

Finally, a more complete collection of clustering evaluation measures can be found in [this review](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10791-008-9066-8).